# How can I increase a variable each time I run a bot command?

Tags: c#

I have an int that each time you run a command in discord gets higher by 1. I want something like this:

```
int a = 0;

// my bot command
commands.CreateCommand("test")

Do.( =>
{
    a = a + 1;
});
```

Comment: inside test command body, put the statement a+=1

Answer (score 3):

```
int a = 0;

commands.CreateCommand("test")
a++;
```

you can also use a+=1 to increase your number with 1

//edit
In your code it would look like

```
Do.( =>
{
   a++;
});
```

Comment: If it is working for you leave a comment that I know and feel free to leave a green tick :D

Comment: I am getting the following error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1593 Delegate 'Func<CommandEventArgs, Task>' does not take 0 argument. What do I do?

Comment: Can you send your code? Or edit the question? pleasew

Comment: int a = 0;

            commands.CreateCommand("test")
             .Do( () =>
            {
                a = a + 1;
            });